# Get windows logged user on REST Web Api

Tags: c#, rest, iis, kendo-ui, windows-authentication

I have a REST API already up and running. Now I'm trying to do a log service.

The idea is to log on a database table all operations made by the user on the client app.

Since it is for internal usage (only used on intranet) I'm using Windows Authentication (`<authentication mode="Windows" />`).

The log service is already working with one problem. I can't get the logged user.

If I run the API and the client app on my local machine, I can get my user. But when I publish I can't.

**What I already tried:**

```
string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

string userName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

string userName = Environment.UserName;
```

I get all sorts of userNames (`IUSR`, `IIS APPPOOL\MyApi`, `MyApi` and also blank) but not the windows logged user.

I have **Windows Authentication** *enable* on IIS.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible? And if it is, how to do it?

Comment: Did you make sure Basic Authentication is off? It is not quite enough to enable Windows Authentication, you also have to disable Basic Authentication. Then the ones based on HttpContext should work. The others are for getting the username of the process running on the server.

Comment: Yes, both basic and anonymous authentication are off.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming by REST API you're meaning ASP.Net Web API.

If so, User.Identity.Name will return the username of the currently authenticated user.

If you haven't added the [Authorize] attribute to your controller (or specific actions) then I would do so in order to disallow anonymous access, which might show you that your configuration isn't set up properly. If that is the case (as I hypothesize) then these tests you've performed have been with anonymously connected users.

Comment: If I add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller and call an action from my client app, I get a 401 (unauthorized) error. But if I type the url on my browser, I get the prompt to enter my credentials. How can I get the prompt on the first time the client calls the API?

Comment: The client is an app with kendo ui (javascript).

Comment: Assuming your ACL is set up properly, only IE passes NTLM by default without prompting. I'll presume you didn't test with IE with that assumption. For any other browser you will have to either type in those credentials, OR use a browser extension and white list that site to pass NTLM credentials.

Comment: @lpfx did you find a solution getting client to talk to API?

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, under the Authentication/Windows Authentication, there is a "Providers..." action.  Click on that and move NTLM up over Negotiate.  I've had to do this in the past in order to get the current user's identity instead of the application pool's identity.